# android photo app error

Tags: java, android

I'm working on an android tutorial for taking pictures.The app has a button that is pressed and then your picture is taken. I don't have much knowledge about coding in either java or android and I would like some advice on my problem. Eclipse can't 
seem to recognize  setOnClickListner,onClickListener,and OnClick. However,eclipse doesn't say anything about imports.

Thanks

```
package com.example.pictureproject;

import java.io.File;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private static String logtag ="CameraApp8";
    private static int TAKE_PICTURE = 1;
    private Uri imageUri;   

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button cameraButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_camera);/*possibly button camera 1*/
        cameraButton.setOnClickListener(cameraListener);
    }
    private OnClickListener cameraListener = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v){
            takePhoto(v);
        }
    };
    private void takePhoto(View v){
        Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
        File photo = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),"picture.jpg");
        imageUri = Uri.fromFile(photo);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);
   startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PICTURE);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent){
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);

        if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
            Uri selectedImage = imageUri;
            getContentResolver().notifyChange(selectedImage, null);

            ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image_camera);
            ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
            Bitmap bitmap;

            try{
                bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(cr,selectedImage);
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, selectedImage.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }catch(Exception e){
                Log.e(logtag,e.toString());
            }
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've imported the wrong `OnClickListener`.

Change

```
import android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener;
```

to

```
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
```